# Replacing a special character does not work with gsub

Tags: r, gsub, stringr

I have a table with many strings that contain some weird characters that I'd like to replace with the "original" ones. Ä became Ã¤, ö became Ã¶, so I replace each Ã¶ with an ö in the text. It works, however, ß became Ã < U+009F> and I am unable to replace it...

```
# Works just fine:
gsub('Ã¶', 'REPLACED', "Testing string Ã¶")


# this does not work
gsub("Ã<U+009F>", "REPLACED", "Testing string Ã<U+009F> ")

# this does not work as well...
gsub("â<U+0080><U+0093>", "REPLACED", "Testing string â<U+0080><U+0093> ")
```

How do I tell R to replace These parts with some letter I want to insert?

Comment: Some advice: The weird characters are obviously due to some encoding issue. It might be worthwhile to deal with this issue while reading in the file, rather than later using regex. You can use `readr`'s packages for this. Use `guess_encoding("file.txt")` to find the encoding, then import with `read_csv("file.txt", locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))`, where "ISO-8859-1" can be swapped out for whatever encoding `guess_encoding` suggests ("ISO-8859-1" is just a suggestion because of the umlauts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the `+` symbol, as it is a `regex` command.

```
> gsub("Ã<U\\+009F>", "REPLACED", "Testing string Ã<U+009F> ")
[1] "Testing string REPLACED "

> gsub("â<U\\+0080><U\\+0093>", "REPLACED", "Testing string â<U+0080><U+0093> ")
[1] "Testing string REPLACED "
```

Answer (score 1):

As there are metacharacters (`+` - to signify one or more), in order to evaluate it literally either escape (as @boski mentioned in the solution) or use `fixed = TRUE`

```
sub("Ã<U+009F>", "REPLACED", "Testing string Ã<U+009F> ", fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "Testing string REPLACED "
```